# Foreach loop and writing the results to a file

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm working on a script which iterates through all users found across a domain, grabs a few credentials and then returns them in the format of an SQL `INSERT` statement which I want stored in a .txt file as output.

So far I've only been able to write the last user to a file however I'm able to print out in the terminal every single user. I have a feeling that I'm overwriting the .txt output file each time I iterate through my foreach loop.

Below is my code which has been sanitised:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Properties uidNumber, sAMAccountName -SearchBase' OU=LiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=local' -Filter *

$message = ""

Set-Content -Path C:\Desktop\UIDs\currentList.txt -Value $null   # ensures file is blank

foreach ($user in $users | Select-Object -Property uidNumber, sAMAccountName){
#Search in specified OU and List above for UID and name and write to a file

$message = "INSERT INTO `DataBaseNameHere`.`currentUser` (`User_id`, `User_name`) VALUES ('" + $user.uidNumber + "', '" + $user.sAMAccountName + "');" |
Out-File -FilePath C:\Desktop\UIDs\currentList.txt
}

Get-Content -Path C:\Desktop\UIDs\currentList.txt
```

I've tried other variations of `foreach` loops, `Out-File` and `Tee-Object` so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after taking elements from a few of your answers I was able to modify my code and fix the loop. I was just using the *Out-File* cmdlet wrong.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Properties uidNumber, sAMAccountName -SearchBase 'OU=LiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=myCompany,DC=local' -filter *
Clear-Content -Path C:\Desktop\UIDs\CurrentList.txt
foreach ($user in $users ){
    “INSERT INTO `databasename`.`currentUser` (`User_id`, `User_name`) VALUES ('"+ $user.uidNumber + "','"+ $user.sAMAccountName +"');" | 
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Desktop\UIDs\CurrentList.txt -Append
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sanitized code you provided does what you want except for leaving only a single line in the output file, you need to ensure that you have either no existing output file or that it's blank, and then you add the `-append` switch to the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Properties uidNumber, sAMAccountName -SearchBase 'OU=LiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=local' -Filter *

Set-Content -Path C:\Desktop\UIDs\CurrentList.txt -Value $null   # ensures file is blank

    foreach ($user in $users | Select-Object -Property uidNumber, sAMAccountName) {

    $message = "INSERT INTO `databaseNameHere`.`currentUser` (`User_id`, `User_name`) VALUES ('" + $user.uidNumber + "', '" + $user.sAMAccountName + "');"
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Desktop\UIDs\currentList.txt -append # -append added to not overwrite existing content.
    }
```

See [`Out-File` at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Note that out-file defaults to unicode encoding appending, even if a preexisting file is ascii.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted would not write anything to a file since the loop defines `$message` without doing anything with it, and then calls `Out-File` without any input.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
Get-ADUser ... |
    Select-Object uidNumber, sAMAccountName |
    ForEach-Object { "INSERT INTO `databaseNameHere`.`currentUser` (...);" } |
    Out-File -FilePath C:\Desktop\UIDs\currentList.txt
```

Beware though, that building `INSERT` statements that way is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and should be avoided.